# Tensorflow maxpool with dynamic ksize

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code for a convolutional layer on TensorFlow. This layer is part of a larger computational graph.

```
# Define the shape of the filter
filter_shape = [1,
                config.char_filter_size,
                config.dim_char,
                config.dim_char]

# Define the convolutional layer weights and biases
W_conv = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1),
                     name="W_conv")
b_conv = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[config.dim_char]),
                     name="b_conv")
# Do 2d convolution
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(char_embeddings,
                    W_conv,
                    strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                    padding="VALID",
                    name="conv")
# Apply nonlinearity
# h_conv has the same shape as conv
h_conv = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b_conv),
                    name="conv_relu")
# Maxpooling h_conv over dim 2 (char dim)

# ERROR HERE
conv_pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv,
                             ksize=[1, 1, tf.shape(h_conv)[-2], 1],
                             strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                             padding='VALID',
                             name="conv_max_pool")
```

When trying to run, I get the error:

> TypeError: Expected int for argument 'ksize' not tf.Tensor shape=() dtype=int32.

is `tf.nn.max_pool` unable to handle dynamic `ksize`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you simply want to find the largest value over one of the dimensions which may be of dynamic size.
If that is the case, you are probably better off using the [`tf.reduce_max()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_max) function instead of `tf.nn.max_pool()`.

```
tf.reduce_max(
    h_conv,
    axis=2,
    keep_dims=True
)
```

I set `keep_dims=True` because it corresponds to what you would get if max pooling worked, but it is probably easier to work with the result if you set `keep_dims=False`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with 'dynamic ksize`. [tf.nn.max_pool](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool) takes

> a list of ints that has length >= 4

You have a list, but the 3-rd element is [not an integer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#shape) but a

> A Tensor of type tf.int32.

So you should evaluate this value in session, extract the int from it and only after that you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

As previously stated, k_size expects a list of integers not a list of Tensors. However, there is a fix applied. You can use:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_nn_ops
conv_pooled = gen_nn_ops.max_pool_v2(
conv,
ksize=[1,1, tf.shape(h_conv)[-2], 1],
strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
padding='VALID',
name="pool")
```

Comment: There are more details on this here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/11875