# How can I call `tf.nn.avg_pool2d()` with tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to call `tf.nn.avg_pool2d()` inside a function decorated with `@tf.fuction`. How do I have to pass the parameters `ksize` and `strides`?

Both, `ksize` and `strides` change during execution. Therefore, I store them in a `tf.Variable`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        self.lod_in = tf.Variable(initial_value=5.0, name='level of detail', trainable=False)
        self.k_size = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1, 1, 1, 1], trainable=False)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = inputs
        x = self.special_method(x)
        return x

    @tf.function
    def special_method(self, x):
        factor = int(2 ** tf.floor(self.lod_in))
        print(type(factor))

        # Method 1 - TypeError: Expected int for argument 'ksize' not <tf.Tensor 'Cast:0' shape=() dtype=int8>.
        ksize = [1, factor, factor, 1]
        x = tf.nn.avg_pool2d(x, ksize=ksize, strides=ksize, padding='VALID')

        # Method 2 - AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
        # self.k_size.assign([1, factor, factor, 1])
        # x = tf.nn.avg_pool2d(x, ksize=self.k_size, strides=self.k_size, padding='VALID')
        return x

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(MyModel, self).get_config()
        return config



model = MyModel()
model.compile()

x = tf.ones(shape=[8, 128, 128, 16])
y = model(x)
```

## Edit

I run my code in graph mode and would like to change `self.lod_in` during execution after a certain amount of steps.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.nn.avg_pool2d` expects a python `int` or a list of `int`, not a Tensor. Just use normal python lists or integer.

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/avg_pool) (emphasis is mine):

> Args
>
> - input   Tensor of rank N+2, of shape [batch_size] +
>   input_spatial_shape + [num_channels] if data_format does not start
>   with "NC" (default), or [batch_size, num_channels] +
>   input_spatial_shape if data_format starts with "NC". Pooling happens
>   over the spatial dimensions only.
> - ksize   **An int or list of ints** that
>   has length 1, N or N+2. The size of the window for each dimension of
>   the input tensor.
> - strides     **An int or list of ints** that has length 1, N
>   or N+2. The stride of the sliding window for each dimension of the
>   input tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import math

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        self.lod_in = 5.0

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = inputs
        x = self.special_method(x)
        return x

    @tf.function
    def special_method(self, x):
        factor = int(2 ** math.floor(self.lod_in))
        ksize = [1, factor, factor, 1]
        x = tf.nn.avg_pool2d(x, ksize=ksize, strides=ksize, padding='VALID')

        return x

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(MyModel, self).get_config()
        return config
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Please see my edit for clarification

Comment: I'm not sure I see how your edit relates to this answer. Nothing prevents you to change a Python value after a certain number of steps in graph mode.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53242345/1702527). However, it is only implemented for `max_pooling` but not for `average_pooling`.

```py
from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_nn_ops
conv_pooled = gen_nn_ops.max_pool_v2(
conv,
ksize=[1,1, tf.shape(h_conv)[-2], 1],
strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
padding='VALID',
name="pool")
```